# What did he just say?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've beaten Diablo 3 a few times now, but I admit during the play through I'm prone to loot fever. Usually, this results in me skipping through the lore from the various NPCs in search of my next phat loot.

Is there a compiled version of the various dialogues available on the web?

Comment: A few times? It has only been out a week now! How often are you playing?

Comment: A lot, now I'm mainly throwing my face at mobs in inferno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Diablo 3 Database has very extensive and complete entries for every bit of quest dialog in the game.

For example, here's the [entry for the first quest in Act 1](http://d3db.com/quest/i/the-fallen-star/66) - you can follow the various links to view whatever quest dialog you're interested in.  Sadly, if you want to read the lore entries or NPC dialog options, you'll have to know what quest phase they first unlock in, as that's the way the data is organized.

I also found [this hubpage](http://hubpages.com/topics/games-toys-and-hobbies/computer-and-video-games/roleplaying-video-games/1852) which has several of the characters' complete dialog listings.  For example, [Deckard Cain's](http://soe.hubpages.com/hub/Deckard-Cain-Lore-and-Character-Dialogue-Guide-Diablo-3) dialog.

Comment: That's a great resource for the quest dialogues, but I couldn't find any of the non-quest dialogue that covers a lot of background material.

Comment: @Rapida, I could've sworn I was *just* looking at that.  I'll double check, but for now I'll take that out of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the books and messages you pick up from the ground as you go or gain as a result of killing a new monster, your journal keeps them all stored (in order you got them too!).  You can either read the text or have it play back the audio.  Hit <kbd>J</kbd> to access this feature.